# Error after opening kali linux in windows terminal using wsl2

Tags: linux, kali-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal, wsl2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3atzy.png)Everytime I open the Windows-Terminal or Kali Linux using WSL-2 I'm getting this message and don't know how to fix it. I'm new to Linux and couldn't find the answers.

See Image:
[image: See Image]

Comment: The error is due to a syntax error in your PATH variable more than likely.

Comment: Can you share your `.bashrc` file?

Comment: @Ramhound so how can i solve it ?

Comment: @Mureinik I have added an image of the path written in my .bashrc file. Hope it can help to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You have spaces in your paths. You need to escape them, e.g., by quoting them:

```
export PATH="/mnt/c/Program Files/Notepad++/":/path/to/other/stuff
```